# What does the term "instantaneous variance" mean?

Tags: standard-deviation, stochastic-processes

What does "instantaneous variance" mean physically - is it just the real, equilibrium variance of a distribution?

I know there is this question
[Difference between instantaneous and long term variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405969/difference-between-instantaneous-and-long-term-variance)
but it has no answer.

I'm asking because a review on sensing concentrations in biochemical networks (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-015-1440-5) uses the instantaneous variance $\sigma_{n}^2$ in formula 2, and links it to the standard deviation of the mean after $N$ measurements as $\sigma_n/\sqrt{N}$. I am confused because when the molecules that make up the concentration that is being measured are uniformly distributed, it seems like (?) the long-term variance should scale with the area over which the measurement is being taken (and go to zero if the area is large enough). But what does the instantaneous variance do?

Comment: That paper clearly defines the instantaneous variance as a parameter $p(1-p)$ of the system.

Comment: The parameter $p$ was not in my question, and $p(1-p)$ does incidentally also not correspond to the instantaneous variance (you've missed the $c^2$ in the denominator). Also this does not explain what it means physically.

Comment: I am only quoting your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the variance of a random variable per unit time, **as the time interval approaches zero**.
You can find the variance of n(t) using autocorrelation time of the signal n(t) and integration time (T).